# Select2 example is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to use [Select2.js plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/). I have created a fiddle of the simplest example of select2 but i can't figure out why this is not working ?

http://jsbin.com/edeseh/2/edit

you can see in the fiddle that selection of items in selectlist and allow clear is not working.

Can anybody please help me, what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 11):

You should use options value to enable selection

and

you should use an empty option for showing placeholder and `allowClear` option.

Here is the working fiddle :

http://jsbin.com/edeseh/8/edit

Main code copied from the link:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="e2" style="width:200px;">
  <option value=""><option>
  <option value="1">Mustard</option>
  <option value="2">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="3">Relish</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#e2").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a State",
  allowClear: true
});
```

Comment: Nice. The Select2 docs make no mention of an empty option for the placeholder. It's easy to assume that it will be prepended automatically.

Comment: The docs now mention placing an empty option - look under "Placeholders":  https://select2.github.io/options.html

Comment: Is it just me or is the fiddle not working? It just shows the old style select?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/huhewujira/edit?html,js,output  

Updated JsBin Link. In original answer CDN links used in jsbin were expired.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions require you to add 'select2' class in the dropdown.

Comment: Can you please explain this a little more? :)

Comment: add "select2" as class in dropdown which is a requirement in older versions